# Yii2 swiftmailer foreach multiple email

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer, yii2-basic-app

I want to run a code to send email to all users. At first i used this code to run a test.

```
->setTo([
                'john.doe@gmail.com' => 'John Doe',
                'jane.doe@gmail.com' => 'Jane Doe',
        ])
```

I found out that the mail is 1 mail sent to multiple recipents, while i need to 2 emails to 2 recipients. Because in reality i need to send to over hundred people at once. SO i try foreach loop.

```
   public function contact($email)
    {
        $users = Users::find()->all();
        $content = $this->body;
    foreach($users as $user){
        if ($this->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose("@app/mail/layouts/html", ["content" => $content])

                ->setTo($user->email)
                ->setFrom($email)
                ->setSubject($user->fullname . ' - ' . $user->employee_id . ': ' . $this->subject)
                ->setTextBody($this->body)
                ->send();

            return true;
        }
    }
        return false;

    }
```

But it only run 1 loop and end.
Please tell me where i'm wrong.
Thank you

Comment: what is in `$this->validate()` where is that function ?

Comment: added an answer see if that helps you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason just one mail is sent is the

```
return true
```

it returns after the first email is sent, you should use `try{}catch(){}` like below

```
public function contact($email) {
        $users = Users::find()->all();
        $content = $this->body;

        try {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                if ($this->validate()) {
                    $r = Yii::$app->mailer->compose("@app/mail/layouts/html", ["content" => $content])
                            ->setTo($user->email)
                            ->setFrom($email)
                            ->setSubject($user->fullname . ' - ' . $user->employee_id . ': ' . $this->subject)
                            ->setTextBody($this->body)
                            ->send();
                    if (!$r) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error sending the email to '.$user->email);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            //display messgae
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            //or display error in flash message
            //Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error',$ex->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You can either return `false` in the `catch` part or return the error message rather than returning `false` and where ever you are calling the `contact` function check it the following way.

```
if(($r=$this->contact($email))!==true){
    //this will display the error message
    echo $r;
}
```